# Tkinter. Text. Python2.7. Не выводится текст

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, python-2.7

Проблема заключается в следующем: при нажатии на кнопку "вперёд" или "назад" меняется изображение (это работает) и вместе с ним должен выводится текст в другой виджет.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-#
#Импорт библиотек#
import sys,os
sys.path.append("mdls/")

from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import Tkinter,tkMessageBox
#import textf as tf

#Создание трёх основных виджетов#
root_image = Tkinter.Tk()
root_image.geometry("400x400+100+140")
root_image.title("Изображения")

root_text = Tkinter.Toplevel()
root_text.geometry("600x400+300+300")
root_text.title("Текст")

buttons_frame = Tkinter.Toplevel()
buttons_frame.title("Управление")
buttons_frame.geometry("300x30+0+0")
buttons_frame.resizable(0,0)

import glob

image_list = glob.glob("images/*.gif")
text_list = glob.glob("text/*.txt")

current_image = 0
current_text = 0

def program_information():
    info_widget = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    info_widget.title("Информация")
    info_widget.geometry("595x650+650+100")
    info_widget.resizable(0,0)

    who_created = ("\t|Создал NAME NAME | 2015 год|")
    text= Tkinter.Text(info_widget,font=("consolas",12),
                       width=len(who_created),height=1,
                       fg="lightblue",bg="black",wrap=Tkinter.WORD)
    text.pack()

    text.insert(1.0,who_created)

    info_linky_image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="mdls/title_demo_image.gif")
    info_label = Tkinter.Label(info_widget,image=info_linky_image)
    info_label.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)

    tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="Производим велосипеды уже три года")

    info_widget.mainloop()

def change_image(delta):
    global current_image,current_text,image_list,text_list

    current_image += delta
    current_text += delta

    image = Image.open(image_list[current_image])
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    textf = Tkinter.Text(root_text)#,font=("times",14))
    textf.insert(Tkinter.END, open("text/txt"+str(current_image)+".txt").read())

    image_label['text'] = image_list[current_image]
    image_label['image'] = photo
    image_label.photo = photo


#Область изображений#
image_label = Tkinter.Label(root_image, compound=Tkinter.TOP)
image_label.pack()

#Область текста#
text_label = Tkinter.Text(root_text)
text_label.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
#text_label.insert(1.0,sorted(os.listdir("images/")))

#Описание действий кнопок#
Tkinter.Button(buttons_frame, text="Назад",relief=Tkinter.GROOVE,
               command=lambda: change_image(-1)).pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)

Tkinter.Button(buttons_frame,relief=Tkinter.GROOVE,
               text="Вперёд", command=lambda: change_image(+1)).pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)

Tkinter.Button(buttons_frame, text="Выход",relief=Tkinter.GROOVE,
               command=root_image.destroy).pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)

Tkinter.Button(buttons_frame, text="Информация",relief=Tkinter.GROOVE,
               command=program_information).pack()

#Завершение программы#
change_image(0)

root_text.mainloop()
root_image.mainloop()
```

Comment: Очень плохой код! Нет обработки зависимостей (пакет PIL сторонняя библиотека). Метод mainloop в коде должен быть всего один! Что это за 

    root_text.mainloop()
    root_image.mainloop()

странные мантры? Это первое. Второе - для дочерних окон  (Toplevel) лучше использовать wait_window вместо mainloop. Не запускал ваш код, но после вставки текста в текстовое поле попробуйте применить метод update.

Comment: Учту ваши замечания, ибо с "Tkinter" начал знакомиться недавно. И на счёт сторонних бибилотек не волнуйтесь -- всё установится с помощью ".sh" или ".bat" скриптов. 
Метод "update()" ничего не дал.

Answer (score 1):

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import choice

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
texts = ('qwe','dfgh','2345wg','.,mnlwert','@#$%@#$%')

def click(event):
    label['text'] = choice(texts)
    #print(dir(text))
    text.delete('1.0',END)
    text.insert(0.0,label['text'])

label = Label(root,text='hi')
label.pack()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

root.bind('<1>',click)
root.mainloop()
```